# Android In App purchase - Could not find a method

Tags: android, android-fragments, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial) to implement in-app purchases, however I'm doing it in a fragment. For both the public void buttonClicked and public void buyClick it says they have never been used, making the app crash when the button is press. I'm not sure whats going wrong.

Error is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method buyClick(View) in the activity class

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment {

    IabHelper mHelper;
    private Button clickButton;
    private Button buyButton;
    private static final String TAG =
            "com.appal.inappbilling";
    static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1,
                container, false);



      Button buyButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buyButton);

          Button clickButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
            clickButton.setEnabled(false);

        String base64EncodedPublicKey =
                "MYKEY";

        mHelper = new IabHelper(getActivity(), base64EncodedPublicKey);

        mHelper.startSetup(new
                                   IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                       public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
                                       {
                                           if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                               Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                                                       result);
                                           } else {
                                               Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                           }
                                       }
                                   });



        return view;
    }
    public void buttonClicked (View view)
    {
        clickButton.setEnabled(false);
        buyButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
    public void buyClick(View view) {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), ITEM_SKU, 10001,
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                 Intent data)
    {
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
                resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                          Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle error
                return;
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
                consumeItem();
                buyButton.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    };
    public void consumeItem() {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
    }

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
            = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                             Inventory inventory) {

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle failure
            } else {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                        mConsumeFinishedListener);
            }
        }
    };
    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
            new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
                public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                              IabResult result) {

                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        clickButton.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        // handle error
                    }
                }
            };
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }

 }

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Fragment_1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Listen to"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#DEC779" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="gfhfghfg"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:gravity="center"/>

<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
 android:layout_above="@id/textView2">

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/buyButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Best"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="buyClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clickButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Feel"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that hosting Activity is receiving button clicks not the fragment. You could set listeners to corresponding buttons with `.setOnClickListener()` or do something like this in your hosting activity:

```
public void buyClick(View view) {
   Fragment_1_instance.buyClick(view);
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I ended but doing but thanks anyway but now it just does nothing. Made a new question on it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247702/in-app-purchase-nothing-happens-android