# In App Purchase Nothing happens Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Following [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial#Implementing_the_onActivityResult_Method) guide on in app purchases. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but any help would be amazing! Quite tricky as its in a fragment not the usual activity. Only thing in logs is ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP and then ACTION_DOWN.

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment {

IabHelper mHelper;
private Button clickButton;
private Button buyButton;
private static final String TAG =
        "com.appal.inappbilling";
static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1,
            container, false);


    buyButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
    buyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonClicked(v);
        }
    });

    clickButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v2) {
            buyClick(v2);
        }
    });
    clickButton.setEnabled(false);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey =
            "MYKEY";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(getActivity(), base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new
                               IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                                                   result);
                                       } else {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                       }
                                   }
                               });

    return view;

}
public void buttonClicked (View v)
{
    clickButton.setEnabled(false);
    buyButton.setEnabled(true);
}
public void buyClick(View v2) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent data) {
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            return;
        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            consumeItem();
            buyButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
};

public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    clickButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    // handle error
                }
            }
        };

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}


}
```

Comment: Did you check if these listeners are actually called? Add some logs in buttonClicked and buyClick

Comment: How would I check that? Sorry I'm kinda new to this

Comment: Add break point or some Log.e("tag", "onClick") in your onClicks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the IabBroadcastReceiver.IabBroadcastListener implementation in the fragment.

Current

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment { 
  .....
}
```

Modify Like this

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment implements 

    IabBroadcastReceiver.IabBroadcastListener{ 
          .....


          .....
          @Override
        public void receivedBroadcast() {
            android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Received broadcast notification. Querying inventory.");
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }

        }
```